# unicode character sometimes renders, sometimes doesn't

Tags: helm, fonts, unicode

I'm not sure this is specific to helm, but when in helm's `helm-ucs` (`C-c h 8`) (though this also happens with [`helm-unicode`](https://github.com/shosti/helm-unicode)), I notice that some characters show the weird little box glyph as if the character can't be rendered, but then when I actually "select" them in helm, they do render. This seems very curious, and so I myself am curious as to what could be causing this.

In the following example, consider the character `RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH NOTCHED TAIL`, though this happens with all of the other characters that show boxes.

Not selected:

[image: not selected]

Selected:

[image: selected]

Comment: A shot in the dark: different font-faces in action. One of them has unicode glyphs, the other doesn't. And they switch when you interact with the text.

Comment: What @wvxvw said - one font supports the char; another doesn't support it.

Comment: You can easily check whether this is Helm-specific, and if not, remove that part of your question (and tag `helm`), to simplify it. Try just inserting the same character into a buffer (that uses the same font) using `C-x 8 RET`. E.g., `C-x 8 RET rightwards arrow with notched tail RET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Drew and wvxvw. I'm convinced you guys are correct, although I don't think I can prove it anymore. It confounds me, but somehow after restarting emacs a couple times in between changes to my init.el (with no even remotely font-related changes), this behavior changed so that even when I selected the candidate it still showed the box.

So I went to my font-related configuration and noticed that somehow I had this:

```el
;; Incorrect code below!
(cond
 ((eq system-type 'darwin)
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-default" nil "Symbola" nil 'append))
 ((eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
  (set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Apple Color Emoji") nil 'prepend)
  (set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Apple Symbols") nil 'append)))
```

Somehow my OSes there were flipped, so I wasn't setting Symbola even though I'm on linux. I fixed that and now everything is perfectly fine.